# Which direction are wild beehives combs oriented?

Tags: entomology, environment

Is it on the North-South axis, the East-West axis or some other orientation?

Answer (score 1):

I've usually observed wild Indian Bees (Apis cerana) orient their hives in an East-West direction. The entrances are usually oriented towards the Sun.

This is purely from my own observation (in South India) and not from any research.

Comment: So are the combs parallel or perpendicular to the E-W axis ?